# One form is working while other form is not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've UserController in which I've two options -

1) For Updating Profile

2) For Updating Password

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function profile(){
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request){
        if(isset($request->avatar) && $request->avatar->getClientOriginalName()){
            $ext = $request->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->avatar->storeAs('public/avatar',$file);

        }
        else
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if(!$user->avatar)
                $file = '';
            else
                $file = $user->avatar;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $file;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->mb_number = $request->mb_number;
            $user->home_town = $request->home_town;
            $user->save();

        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));

    }

    public function update_password(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), $user['password']) && Input::get('new_password') == Input::get('confirm_new_password')){
            $user->password = bcrypt(Input::get('new_password'));
            $user->save();
        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

}
```

In my view blade, I've two forms -

1. update_avatar for updating profile like name, phone number and avatar.
2. update_password for updating password.

   ```
           </div>
           <div class="widget-user-image">
             <img class="img-circle" src="{{ asset('public/storage/avatar/'.$user->avatar) }}" alt="User Avatar">

           </div>
           <div class="box-footer">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 border-right">
                 <div class="description-block">
                   <h5 class="description-header">{{ $user->email }}</h5>
                   <span class="description-text">Email</span>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.description-block -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col -->
               <div class="col-sm-4 border-right">
                 <div class="description-block">
                   <h5 class="description-header">{{ $user->name }}</h5>
                   <span class="description-text">{{ $user->home_town }}</span>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.description-block -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col -->
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div class="description-block">
                   <h5 class="description-header">{{ $user->mb_number }}</h5>
                   <span class="description-text">Phone No.</span>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.description-block -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.col -->
             </div>
             <!-- /.row -->
           </div>
           <!--
           <div class="box-footer no-padding">
             <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
               <li><a href="#">Projects <span class="pull-right badge bg-blue">31</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Tasks <span class="pull-right badge bg-aqua">5</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Completed Projects <span class="pull-right badge bg-green">12</span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Followers <span class="pull-right badge bg-red">842</span></a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
           -->
         </div>
         </div>

             <section class="content">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                   <form action="/profile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="name">Name</label>
                               <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Title" value="{{$user->name}}">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="email">Email</label>
                               <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Description" value="{{$user->email}}" readonly>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="mb_number">Mobile No.</label>
                               <input type="text" name="mb_number" class="form-control" id="mb_number" placeholder="Schedule" value="{{$user->mb_number}}">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="home_town">Home Town</label>
                               <input type="text" name="home_town" class="form-control" id="home_town" placeholder="Deadline" value="{{$user->home_town}}">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Update Profile Image</label>
                               <input type="file" name="avatar">
                               @if($user->avatar)
                               <img src="{{ asset('public/storage/avatar/'.$user->avatar) }}" style="width:150px;">
                               @endif
                           </div>
                       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"
                       <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"></a>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
   </section>

   <section class="content">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                   <form action="/profile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="old_password">Old Password</label>
                               <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control" id="old_password" placeholder="Old Password">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="new_password">New Password</label>
                               <input type="password" name="new_password" class="form-control" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="confirm_new_password">Confirm New Password </label>
                               <input type="password" name="confirm_new_password" class="form-control" id="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm New Password">
                           </div>
                       <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"
                       <a href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"></a>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Password</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
   </section>
   ```

update_password function is working fine but update_avatar function is not working neither it's showing any error. I've tried dd($user) but still not giving output to dd.

Comment: if nothing happens and dd($user) doesn't call. that means the first if contition is false `if(isset($request->avatar) && $request->avatar->getClientOriginalName())`.

Comment: `form action="/profile"` for both forms?

Comment: I think your second form is not closed properly

Comment: and why are you redirecting to  the  same url ? can you please show us  us your route ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out i updated form a bit with indentation and proper closing, also please redirect profile avatar to different URL so that it can access different method :-

I would suggest you to use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html , by using form collective it would be much more easier to implement more complex form structure.

In Route,

```
Route::post('/profile_avatar',"UserController@update_avatar");   
Route::post('/profile_password',"UserController@update_password");
```

In Blade,

```
 <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form action="/profile_avatar" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Name
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Title" type="text" value="{{$user->name}}">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Description" readonly="" type="text" value="{{$user->email}}">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mb_number">
                            Mobile No.
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="mb_number" name="mb_number" placeholder="Schedule" type="text" value="{{$user->mb_number}}">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="home_town">
                            Home Town
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="home_town" name="home_town" placeholder="Deadline" type="text" value="{{$user->home_town}}">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            Update Profile Image
                        </label>
                        <input name="avatar" type="file">
                            @if($user->avatar)
                            <img src="{{ asset('public/storage/avatar/'.$user->avatar) }}" style="width:150px;">
                                @endif
                            </img>
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <input <a="" class="btn btn-info" href="" name="_token" type="submit" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Update
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form action="/profile_password" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="old_password">
                            Old Password
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="old_password" name="old_password" placeholder="Old Password" type="password">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new_password">
                            New Password
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirm_new_password">
                            Confirm New Password
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="confirm_new_password" name="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm New Password" type="password">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <input <a="" class="btn btn-info" href="" name="_token" type="submit" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Update Password
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Token mismatch exception.

Comment: Working. Thank you so much. Used same blade, changed form action of both form.

Comment: Got a problem. It's not udpating password. It's redirecting update_avatar on clicking on password update button.

Comment: Can you please approve my answer as solved or provide your answer and check as solved the issue ?

Comment: It's not yet solved. Update Password is not working. I'll do it once it'll work.

Comment: Resolved. The main problem was closing of both form was not declared.